# How can I extract data in a Word document using Perl?

Tags: perl, ms-word

How to extract the data from a word doc using Perl?

Comment: **What** particular data do you want to extract? On what platform? Do you have a copy of Word installed? Is this a batch job, or is the script going to be invoked by a web server? The title and body of your question are identical, indicating you have not put much thought into formulating your question.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110409/how-can-i-programmatically-convert-word-doc-or-docx-files-into-text-files/1110626#1110626 if you are on Windows and can use `Win32::OLE` and all you want is the text in the document.

Comment: am using windows and i want to extract the abbreviations found in 
that word document.... this is what my task is...

Comment: Can u give me an simple example of reading a word document and printing the data on the command prompt...

Answer (score 2):

If you are not on Windows, I think the best route might be to convert it first.

If you are not using Windows and don't have access to [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::OLE), you can use [OpenOffice to convert the documents](http://www.oooninja.com/2008/02/batch-command-line-file-conversion-with.html).

You could wrap up the script in the link into your Perl program.  Although the link starts with PDF if you read on it can convert it to text.  Also see [this stackoverflow post about converting doc and docx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110409/how-can-i-programmatically-convert-word-doc-or-docx-files-into-text-files).

Comment: Can u give me an simple example of reading a word document and printing its data on the command prompt...

Answer (score 1):

You could use Win32::OLE if the script is to run on a Windows box with Word installed.

What platform are you using? Perhaps [antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) could be invoked?

Answer (score 1):

```
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Enum;

$document = Win32::OLE -> GetObject($ARGV[1]);
open (FH,">$ARGV[0]");

print "Extracting Text ...\n";

$paragraphs = $document->Paragraphs();
$enumerate = new Win32::OLE::Enum($paragraphs);
while(defined($paragraph = $enumerate->Next()))
{
    $style = $paragraph->{Style}->{NameLocal};
    print FH "+$style\n";
    $text = $paragraph->{Range}->{Text};
    $text =~ s/[\n\r]//g;
    $text =~ s/\x0b/\n/g;
    print FH "=$text\n";
}
```

stolen from [here](http://www.wellho.net/solutions/perl-using-perl-to-read-microsoft-word-documents.html)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you'd better use COM interfaces to access Word functionality.

If you want to do it cross-platform think about executing "catdoc" or libwv.

Answer (score 0):

Word docs are no longer flat files. Find a .docx, rename it with a .zip extention, and you can open it up and poke around inside to get a feel for how things are laid out. I would generally agree though that microsoft has provided ways to do this already.