# Text mining MS Word documents?

Tags: text, ms-word, data-mining, text-mining

I have about 30 .docx documents (Résumés) with data about peoples' names, skills and so forth.  I need to populate a spreadsheet with some of this information, and to reduce manual work I thought I could use a text mining approach.

Are there any tools or approaches that would be useful in mining (sort of semi-structured) information from these documents?

Comment: You can get to the contents of the files with tools like [python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx). Getting names, skills, etc out is harder (assuming they don't follow the same format). You can try to hand-code some rules, but if you want this to be more robust, there are commercial tools out there [like this one](http://www.daxtra.com/parsing.html)...

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is using perl, as I know you can [pull from word documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124676/how-can-i-extract-data-in-a-word-document-using-perl) (though that in itself can be tricky) and [populate xml spreadsheets](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pexcel/) using perl modules.

I haven't written perl in anger in a long time, so I can't offer examples of how to do this, but if I were to put something together to do this, I would recommend perl. I am sure someone will say there are equivalent functions in python, and maybe even in Ruby, but perl is what I've used, and I've found it very effective for manipulating/matching/parsing/processing text.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `catdoc` http://www.wagner.pp.ru/~vitus/software/catdoc/ tool which will extract the text contents from an MS Word file, and then after that do whatever text processing you want. I'd probably just `grep` for the existence of certain words in the resume against the output of catdoc. No point in over-engineering a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to read word file in docx or doc ,
docx files are nohing but a fancy container . but doc file is little tricky to extract.

i will tell you some ways to extract text from word

1. .doc/docx >> open with open suit >> user pyUNO with python and get your data.
2. .doc/docx >> using python .docx module and Textract and extract data .
3. .doc/docx >> using R Programming which have many modules like officer and ReporteRS >> extract data .
4. using Text mining for conversion of text from one form to another.