# How can I Import data (text) from a word document into a SQL Server database?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, parsing, ms-word, insertion

I have this huge Word document with data about contact details about people. There are close to 350000 such contact details that needs to be inserted into a database.

How do i do this? Do i convert it into XML and then to database, or should i use some scripting language to parse the word data and insert it into database?

Comment: So you have one! word document with more than 350,000 entries?

Comment: Ask who every gave you the Word document to provide the data in a different format ;)

Comment: Copy it into Excel, get the format you want, save as a text file, and import into SQL Server.  It's an idea.

Comment: haha! Yea ... 350000 Entries spread out over 5 docs... 1 one of them is humongous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the Word document using some scripting language like Perl. Covert it into xml or txt. Once done you can very easily import the data into your database.
Refer the following link for more help: [Convert Word doc or docx files into text files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110409/how-can-i-programmatically-convert-word-doc-or-docx-files-into-text-files)

Answer (score 0):

If it was me, I would write a simple parser in c++ to translate the data into a table or into a format where it is delimited. Then I would either use an SQL api to load the data or php to load the data onto the sql database.